# TypeError: Field 'amount' expected a number but got datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 27, 10, 46, 51, 801087, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

Tags: django, django-models, django-errors

I think I did something wrong and I need to delete it. but i can't fix it. How can I do it?

I migrate and I get this error

```
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 
  1990, in get_prep_value
  raise e.__class__(
  TypeError: Field 'amount' expected a number but got datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 27, 10, 46, 
  51, 801087, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).

  (venv) C:\Users\HP\Desktop\markon>
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
images = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/%Y/%m/%d/')
detail = models.TextField()
keywords = models.CharField(max_length=50)
description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
price = models.FloatField()
sale = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

0008_product_amount.py error file in migrations file

```
# Generated by Django 4.0.3 on 2022-03-27 10:46

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('product', '0007_remove_product_amount'),
 ]

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='product',
        name='amount',
        field=models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True),
    ),
]
```

Comment: You seem to assign a datetime to your `amount`...

Comment: Yes, I did it by mistake. How can I fix?

Comment: Share the migration file where this goes wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by migrate file?

Comment: if you migrate, it will list the file it is migrating, these are stored in `app_name/migrations` the last one that is printed, is thus the one where the error occurs.

Comment: Yup. I shared the required file

Comment: Could you remove the records with the amount field set with datetime value first before applying the migration? Since you've changed the amount field from datetime to integer and there's a records with datetime value in amount field. Django cannot convert those datetime values to integer field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the database and all migrations

and try again

Answer (score 3):

Go to your migrations file.
Change field = models.ForeignKey(default = django.utils.timezone.now) to default = 1 in the migration file.
Run your migrations again. That should fix the bug.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into the migrations folder, look at the migration related to "amount" field and delete it.
2. Run migrations using the "python manage.py makemigrations" command. for this time when you are required to provide the default value on the console, don't provide 'timezone.now';instead provide any integer of your choice(e.g:100) because   amount field expect integer value not 'timezone.now'
3. then run python manage.py migrate command.

Note:if you get the error like django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency main_app.0001_initial on database 'default',just run the following command:
rm db.sqlite3 to remove the database ;makemigrations(using python manage.py makemigrations command) and run migrations using python manage.py migrate as specified above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).